# AppleScript to automate switching user not working in Monterey

Tags: macos, applescript, monterey, control-center

I have the following AppleScript that's supposed to automatically switch to the Administrator user. It worked in Big Sur, but isn't working in Monterey.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar 1
            click its menu bar item "barmar"
        end tell
        
        tell its window "Control Center"
            tell its group 1
                set btns to its buttons
                repeat with btn in btns
                    if name of btn = "Administrator" then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

It gets the following error:

> System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter". Invalid index." 
> number -1719 from group 1 of window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter"

The list of users is popping up, but it's failing on "tell its group 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are targeting the **Fast User Switching** *menu bar item*, then you do not need `tell its group 1` as there is no `group 1`.

Also, you are using far more *code* than necessary, as the following works for me:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Control Center"
        click (first menu bar item of menu bar 1 ¬
            whose value of attribute "AXIdentifier" is "com.apple.menuextra.user")
        click (first button of window "Control Center" whose name is "Administrator")
    end tell
end tell
```

**Notes:**

As coded, it does not matter how **Show fast user switching menu as** is set under **System Preferences** > **Users & Groups** > **Login Options** for the **Fast User Switching** *menu bar item*. It work with **Icon**, **Account Name**, or **Full Name** as it uses a different criteria to click the **Fast User Switching** *menu bar item*.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Monterey** 12.0.1 with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

`attribute "AXIdentifier" "com.apple.menuextra.user"` exists in **macOS Big Sur** and **macOS Monterey**.

Comment: You're right. I got rid of the `tell its group 1` line and matching `end tell`, and it worked.

Comment: I assume this used to be needed because the menu is split into multiple sections: The list of users to switch to, "Login window...", and "Users and Groups preferences...", and you first had to drill into that first section.

Comment: @Barmar, Please see updated answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's even nicer. I do very little AppleScript programming, I don't know its shortcuts. I'm pretty sure I got the original script from discussion.apple.com.

Comment: Have to replace `User` with my actual username.

Comment: @Barmar, RE: "Have to replace `User` with my actual username." --  The _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ as shown in my answer works for me as is, however if changing `User` to e.g. `barmar` does the job for you that's good. Note that I do not have a _user_ named `User`, it's what **Accessibility Inspector** from **Xcode** shows as the `name_ for that _menu item_.

Comment: I get `Can’t get menu bar item "User" of menu bar 1 of application process "Control Center"`

Comment: What option do you have selected in "Show fast user switching menu as"?

Comment: Your version works if I change that from "Account name" to "Icon".

Comment: @Barmar, RE: "What option do you have selected in "Show fast user switching menu as"?" Mine is set to the default **Icon**.

Comment: So apparently "User" is the name of that icon.

Comment: @Barmar, RE: "" --  So apparently "User" is the name of that icon. Yes when set to **Icon**, however please see updated _code_ as it now works regardless of how **Show fast user switching menu as** is set, in order to click that _menu bar item_. Thanks.

Comment: The new version works in my regular account, but in my admin account the script for switching back complains `Can't get attribute "AXIdentifier"`

Comment: @Barmar, The current _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer works for me regardless of how **Show fast user switching menu as** is set and whether run from a **Standard** or **Admin** account, the _attribute_ `AXIdentifier` is set to  `"com.apple.menuextra.user"` in all the combinations I tested it under. Sorry it's late here and I'm done with this for tonight.

Comment: Please see my new question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449779/applescript-for-fast-user-switch-stopped-working-in-ventura as the script stopped working in Ventura.